# Can a SVM with polynomial kernel lead to overfitting?

Tags: svm, kernel-trick, overfitting, polynomial

I'm currently searching for the best set of parameters for a Polynomial Kernel with a grid search. I would like to know if using a high value for Polynomial order (10, 100 or 1000) can lead to overfitting?

Comment: It can! Is there something specific that makes you think that it may not?